# Wpf RadioButton group binding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 3 `RadioButton` in same group. RadioButtons represent 3 different operations to run.
Also i have `Button` "Run".

All RadioButtons have `IsChecked="false"` by default. I need to have `Button` "Run" `IsEnabled="False"` until any of RadioButtons checked. That prevents user from brainless click "Run" before he actually choose what he want to do.

I know how to make it in code behind or in ViewModel, but i wonder is there any way to make this logic in XAML? Any kind of trigger to make Button enabled only if any of RadioButtons checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is still to go for a VM method by using CanCommandExecute for the command the Run button is binded to. You could use some pure XAML too. For exemple:

```
<Grid xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="rbChoice1" EventName="Checked">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    <ei:ConditionalExpression ForwardChaining="Or">
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice1}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice2}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice3}" RightOperand="True"/>
                    </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                </ei:ConditionBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="btnRun" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="rbChoice2" EventName="Checked">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    <ei:ConditionalExpression ForwardChaining="Or">
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice1}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice2}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice3}" RightOperand="True"/>
                    </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                </ei:ConditionBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="btnRun" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="rbChoice3" EventName="Checked">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    <ei:ConditionalExpression ForwardChaining="Or">
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice1}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice2}" RightOperand="True"/>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbChoice3}" RightOperand="True"/>
                    </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                </ei:ConditionBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="btnRun" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width=" 300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RadioButton x:Name="rbChoice1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Choice 1"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbChoice2" Grid.Row="2" Content="Choice 2"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbChoice3" Grid.Row="4" Content="Choice 3"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnRun" Grid.Row="6" Content="Run" IsEnabled="False"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Unfortunatly i:EventTrigger dont take routed events otherwise this could be written with just one EventTrigger. But I think it should be quite easy to extend it to accept routed events.

Andother solution is to write a MultiBindingConverter that takes an array of bools and performs OR operator on them and returns a result. In this way you can just bind IsEnabled property to all IsChecked properties of your radios.